# Jest absolute Import

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, jestjs

i'm using Jest configured on my package.json like this:

```
    "jest": {
        "globalSetup": "./src/testSetup/callSetup.js",
        "preset": "ts-jest",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
        }
    }
```

and my typescript works fine with absolute imports like @/app, but my problem is, when i tried to run my *npm t* jest gives me a error that he cant resolver @/app, i have tried all the possible ways that i know and the ways i found on internet but nothing works for me, anyone know how to solve this?

OBS: if i trie to run without globalSetup works fine, i only use this global to run my server for all tests, this video explain what i'm trying todo but i'm using absolute imports and he dont.
[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iwjiiCGiO0&t=7963s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a work arround, i just need that express server is on for all my tests, then i found this [lib](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test) that run your express based on a `npm command` on `package.json` then run your `npm command` for test, with this i have just one express server up and running.

This was solution i found i think its better then the other things and much simple.